# How to iterate through keys and values of JSON Object in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp

I'm passing in a `JSONObject` into my jsp file. I want to be able to display dynamically all the keys and its associated values in the jsp file. I know how to do this in Java, as I can do this:

```
Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jsonObject.get(key).toString();
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

I am confused as to how to do this in my jsp file. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do not put java code into JSP - use a servlet to convert the JSON into a displayable data structure OR try something like this http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/examples.html